# my region does not have cloud function, can I use other region cloud function, and how about the billing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I want to make a new project using a brand new region, JAKARTA (asia-southeast2).

in my project, I need to use

1. Firestore
2. Cloud Functions
3. Cloud Storage for Firebase

but from the table info [product availability by location in here](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#products-available-by-location) . it seems that cloud functions is not available yet in region JAKARTA (asia-southeast2), asia pacific zone.

here is my questions:

1. for now, can I use cloud functions from the nearest available region ? I mean, my firestore is In Jakarta, but my cloud function is Hongkong/Tokyo ?
2. say for example I can deploy my function in other region, and then in the future, cloud functions is also available in Jakarta (asia-southeast2). can I switch it to cloud function in Jakarta ?
3. If I can deploy the function in other region, then my firestore and storage (Jakarta) will be in different region from my cloud function (Hongkong/Tokyo). will it affect the billing ? I need to consider some additional cost if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For now, can I use cloud functions from the nearest available region ?
> I mean, my firestore is In Jakarta, but my cloud function is
> Hongkong/Tokyo ?

Yes you can have your Cloud Functions and Firestore database (or Cloud Storage buckets) in different regions. See the [recommendations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations?authuser=0#selecting-regions_firestore-storage) for choosing the regions.

> Say for example I can deploy my function in other region, and then in
> the future, cloud functions is also available in Jakarta
> (asia-southeast2). can I switch it to cloud function in Jakarta

Yes, you will be able to change the region, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?authuser=0#modify-region). Note that you could deploy the same CF to different regions.

> If I can deploy the function in other region, then my firestore and
> storage (Jakarta) will be in different region from my cloud function
> (Hongkong/Tokyo). will it affect the billing ? I need to consider some
> additional cost if any.

Yes it will affect you billing in terms of **Outbound data transfer** (i.e. data transferred from your function out to the locations where Firestore and/or Storage are deployed). See the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing?authuser=0#networking) for more details. Note that you could also experience an increased latency.